How to Improve performance of deep learning timeseries forecasting model like LSTM?
I have historical data of 5 years (June 2019- June 2024). Data is in daily & csv file format. I have 4 features: Data, AQI, Raw Concentration, NowCast Concentration. I am trying to forecast only future AQI based on these features. I tried following models:

LSTM/LSTM-CNN/LSTM-RNN
Prophet/ARIMA/SARIMA

For Prophet/ARIMA/SARIMA, i got very poor model performance on both test and train sets.
For LSTM/LSTM-CNN/LSTM-RNN, i am stuck at R2 score 0.81. I tried grid search, drop out, early stopping but performance stays between 0.70 to 0.80. I even tried different dataset(with same features) but still same performance. What else i can do? Here is my simplest model with following test evaluations
Mean Squared Error (MSE): 0.01
,R2 Score: 0.80
,Mean Absolute Error (MAE): 0.05
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Specify the Features
X = [0, 1, 2]  # Indices of input features (AQI, Raw Conc., NowCast Conc.)
Y = [0]        # Index of output feature (AQI)

# Function to create sequences for LSTM
def create_sequences(data, seq_length, input_features, output_features):
    X, y = [], []
    for i in range(len(data) - seq_length):
        # Input sequence (X) is from index i to i + seq_length for specified features
        X.append(data[i:i + seq_length, input_features].astype(np.float32))  
        # Output sequence (y) is the next value (i + seq_length) for specified features
        y.append(data[i + seq_length, output_features].astype(np.float32))   
    
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)

# Set sequence length and split data into train and test sets
seq_length = 30
train_size = int(len(df) * 0.8)
train_data = df.iloc[:train_size].values
test_data = df.iloc[train_size:].values

# Create sequences for LSTM
train_X, train_y = create_sequences(train_data, seq_length, X, Y)
test_X, test_y = create_sequences(test_data, seq_length, X, Y)

# Convert data to PyTorch tensors
train_X = torch.tensor(train_X, dtype=torch.float32)
train_y = torch.tensor(train_y.reshape(-1, 1), dtype=torch.float32)  # Reshape to match output size
test_X = torch.tensor(test_X, dtype=torch.float32)
test_y = torch.tensor(test_y.reshape(-1, 1), dtype=torch.float32)  # Reshape to match output size

# Define LSTM model
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
        out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        return out

# Initialize model parameters
input_size = len(X)    # Number of input features (AQI, Raw Conc., NowCast Conc.)
hidden_size = 100
num_layers = 2
output_size = 1        # Predicting AQI

# Initialize model, loss function, and optimizer
model = LSTMModel(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

# Training the model
num_epochs = 200
train_losses = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(train_X)
    loss = criterion(outputs, train_y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    train_losses.append(loss.item())
    
    if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')

